# rails 2.x Psych::SyntaxError in SessionsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I've got to fix a bug on an old Rails 2.3.8 project and I'm running in to trouble loading the development environment.

I've converted the project to use bundler, here is my Gemfile:

```
source :gemcutter

gem "rails", "2.3.8"

gem "pg"

gem 'rdoc'

gem "haml"
gem "will_paginate", '~> 2.3.11'

# RESTful ACL support.
gem "restful_acl", "3.0.4"

# awesome nested set for sub categories
gem "awesome_nested_set", "< 2.0"

# rspec tests
gem 'machinist', "< 2.0"
gem "rspec", "1.3.0"
gem "rspec-rails", "1.3.2"
gem "test-unit"

# Deployment
gem "capistrano"
```

When I start the server with 'script/server' and load the website up I get the following error

```
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/vendor/i18n-0.3.7/i18n/backend/base.rb:244:in `load_yml'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/vendor/i18n-0.3.7/i18n/backend/base.rb:231:in `load_file'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/vendor/i18n-0.3.7/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `block in load_translations'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/vendor/i18n-0.3.7/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `each'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/vendor/i18n-0.3.7/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `load_translations'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/vendor/i18n-0.3.7/i18n/backend/base.rb:98:in `init_translations'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/vendor/i18n-0.3.7/i18n/backend/base.rb:84:in `available_locales'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/vendor/i18n-0.3.7/i18n.rb:54:in `available_locales'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/vendor/i18n-0.3.7/i18n.rb:118:in `available_locales'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:226:in `valid_locale?'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:243:in `parse_extensions'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:233:in `split'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:118:in `initialize'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/reloadable_template.rb:81:in `initialize'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/reloadable_template.rb:38:in `new'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/reloadable_template.rb:38:in `register_template_from_file'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/reloadable_template.rb:62:in `block in load_all_templates_from_dir'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/reloadable_template.rb:62:in `each'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/reloadable_template.rb:62:in `load_all_templates_from_dir'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/reloadable_template.rb:29:in `[]'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/paths.rb:48:in `block in find_template'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/paths.rb:47:in `each'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_view/paths.rb:47:in `find_template'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1389:in `default_template'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:896:in `render'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `block in render_with_benchmark'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `block in ms'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1326:in `default_render'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1332:in `perform_action'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `block in perform_action_with_benchmark'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `block in ms'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `block in build_middleware_stack'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `block in call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.5/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `block in call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `block in call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `each'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:48:in `service'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/map7/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

I've tried remarking out the sessions controller and it doesn't change the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you were using ruby 1.8.7, and now you are trying to use 1.9.3 which has different YAML parser: http://blog.tddium.com/2011/12/01/psych-isnt-syck/

Also note that rails 2.3 does not support ruby 1.9.3. It would be easiest to use ruby 1.8.7.

Switch to ruby 1.9.2 should not be hard, you would probably need utf8 patch: http://blog.kennejima.com/post/835166063/making-ruby-1-9-rails-2-3-to-play-nice-with-utf-8

Using rails 2.3 with ruby 1.9.3 is not that easy, see: http://developer.uservoice.com/blog/2012/03/04/how-to-upgrade-a-rails-2-3-app-to-ruby-1-9-3/

Answer (score 0):

A work around for this is to not get gems from rubygems.org.  You can do this by specifying a GitHub repo for a gem instead of letting bundler download it from rubygems.org.

The problem is in the charset being served by the host from which you download the rubygem, if I remember correctly.